# Perl Archive::zip -- file doesn't get added

Tags: perl, zip, archive

I am traversing a directory tree (subversion backup) and add every file and directory that I find to a zip file. This works pretty slick. However two files are missing.

```
sub zipFolder
{
    my $dir = 'D:\\SVN-Backup\\EnterpriseDataRepository\\20110502-0630';
    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
    my $zipped = $zip->addDirectory($dir);
    $zipped->desiredCompressionLevel( 9 );
    $zipped->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_DEFLATED );
        print "Before find\n";
    find(\&zip_file, $dir);
    print "after find\n";
    die 'write error' unless $zip->writeToFileNamed('D:/SVN-Backup/CCBuild/backup.zip' ) == AZ_OK;

    sub zip_file 
    {
          print $File::Find::name;
          if ( -d $File::Find::name ) { # just grab directories, not files.
            $zip->addDirectory($File::Find::name);
            print " : dir\n";
         } else { #zip files
           print " : file\n";
           $zip->addFile($File::Find::name) != AZ_OK ||  print "couldn't add file \n";
         }

    }
}
```

The file D:\SVN-Backup\20110502-0630/db/revprops/0/0 will not be added to the zip archive. Any idea what I can do to get the this file added as well?

```
...
D:\SVN-Backup\20110502-0630/db/uuid : file
D:\SVN-Backup\20110502-0630/db/revprops : dir
D:\SVN-Backup\20110502-0630/db/revprops/0 : dir
D:\SVN-Backup\20110502-0630/db/revprops/0/0 : file
D:\SVN-Backup\20110502-0630/db/revprops/0/1 : file
D:\SVN-Backup\20110502-0630/db/revprops/0/10 : file
...
```

---

Congrats to Andy for his contribution. He solved the Problem.

> A related bug:
>   [rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=27463](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=27463),
>   but that's only about files, not
>   directories. What version of
>   Archive::Zip do you have?

I have perl 5.8.8 which does seem to be older than the fix.

Comment: A related bug: http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=27463, but that's only about files, not directories. What version of Archive::Zip do you have? Also, you're mixing / and \ path separators, I don't whether that could cause problems.

Comment: another thought. Does it work better if you disable chdir in File::Find:Rule. I.e. use: find({wanted => \&zip_file, no_chdir => 1}, $dir);

Comment: @Andy: If you put your comment in as an Answer I can even give you the points in addition to the credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [CPAN bug 27463](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=27463), which would explain the issue if you have an older version of Archive::Zip (<= 1.20, as best I can tell from CPAN).

As both snoopy and I guessed, the bug was due to the filename `"0"` being false when used as a condition.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I'm having a look at the source code for Archive::Zip. This addFile method is in [Archive::Zip::Archive](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Archive-Zip/), which in turn calls addMember in the same source file:</strike>

```
sub addMember {
    my $self       = shift;
    my $newMember  = ( ref( $_[0] ) eq 'HASH' ) ? shift->{member} : shift;
    push( @{ $self->{'members'} }, $newMember ) if $newMember;
    return $newMember;
}
```

This sub will fail when $newMember is '0' (false). I think Archive::Zip may need an RT ticket submitted against it, with a patch to fix the above.

Comment: I'm not sure this could be it, `$newMember` is an object here

Comment: @Andy Youre' right. I can actually add  a file named '0' to an archive :-|

Comment: I had the same intuition, and it's still possible there's something about Peter's setup that we haven't replicated, or it may be an instance of the bug that is already fixed (see my comment on the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the whole directory recursively:

```
    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
    $zip->addTree('C:\~~~\some dir', 'new name for dir');
    $zip->writeToFileNamed( 'C:\~~~\great.zip' );
```

This will add directory and  of it's content to zip archive with all relative preserved.